# Is there a solution to fix the problem column in Python?

Tags: tkinter

[Image of my code for the "University System" page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC1TS.png)

```
name_lbl = tk.Label(master, text='نام:', bg='black', fg='red')
name_lbl.grid(column=2, row=0, pady=20)
```

Hello, no matter how much I increase the column of a label whose language is Persian, that label does not move and remains on the left side.
Is there anyone who can help me to solve the problem?
thanks a lot.

Project code link:[text](https://www.useblackbox.io/editor?id=63d341c1-a76b-48ac-8303-96e247a45969)

I expected 'name_lbl' which is 'name:' to be in column 2 but it is in column 0.

Comment: If there is no widget in column 0 and 1, then their widths are zero by default and so widget in column 2 will be at the left-most place.